# Find whether the three terms are AP,GP or HP.

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Question:**

If a,b,c are in a GP and the following expression is true $$a^{\frac{1}{x}}=b^{\frac{1}{y}}=c^{\frac{1}{z}}$$Then x,y,z will be in a GP,AP or HP.

**My attempt:**
Since a,b,c are in a GP, we can say that $b=(ac)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Further 
$$b^{\frac{1}{y}}=a^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

$$((ac)^{\frac{1}{2}})^{\frac{1}{y}}=a^{\frac{1}{x}}$$
$$(ac)^{\frac{1}{2y}}=a^{\frac{1}{x}}$$
Similary 
$$(ac)^{\frac{1}{2y}}=c^{\frac{1}{z}}$$
Multiplying $(ac)^{\frac{1}{2y}}$$(ac)^{\frac{1}{2y}}=a^{\frac{1}{x}}c^{\frac{1}{z}}$

$(a)^{\frac{1}{y}}(c)^{\frac{1}{y}}=a^{\frac{1}{x}}c^{\frac{1}{z}}$

Equating the exponents of a and c terms we get:-

$$\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{x}$$ and $$\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{z}$$

Hence $$x=y=z$$ Therefore a,b,c are AP, GP and HP. But the book says they are in an AP.

Comment: But you cannot equate exponents the way you do. For instance, $3^6\cdot 9^2 = 3^4\cdot 9^3$, but that doesn't mean $6 = 4$ and $2 = 3$. Had $a$ and $c$ been _variables_, and this an equality of _functions_, then yes, barring a few special exceptions involving $1$ and $0$, you could've equated the exponents. But it isn't. It's an equality of real numbers.

Comment: The question would be more readable (and answerable) if you did not rely on initialisms like *AP*, *GP*, or *HP*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with several proofs, but this is the one I like the best.

We are given that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are in geometric progression.  Therefore $\frac{b}{a} = \frac{c}{b}$, or equivalently, $b^2 = ac$.

We want to show that $x$, $y$, and $z$ are in arithmetic progression.  It is enough to show that $y-x=z-y$, or equivalently, $2y = x+z$.

We have
\begin{align*}
    b^2 &= ac = (a^{1/x})^x(c^{1/z})^z \\
        &= (b^{1/y})^x(b^{1/y})^z \\
        &= b^{x/y + z/y} = b^{(x+z)/y}
\end{align*}
Therefore $2 = \dfrac{x+z}{y}$, or $x+z = 2y$.

Answer (score 0):

I would show it with example. Let $a=64,b=16,c=4$.
Then $x=3,y=2,z=1$.They will be in AP.

Comment: You can't prove a general statement by any number of examples, let alone a single example.